# Expressing dimensions in Russian

Tags: словоупотребление, предлоги

1. Дорожка шириной в два метра.
2. Дорожка в два метра ширины.
3. Двухметровая в ширину дорожка.
4. Ширина дорожки два метра.
5. У дорожки ширина два метра.
6. У дорожки два метра ширины.
7. У дорожки два метра в ширину.
8. Дорожка имеет два метра ширины.
9. Дорожка имеет два метра в ширину.
10. Дорожка имеет в ширину два метра.
11. Дорожка имеет ширину в два метра.

Are all these expressions and phrases correct?
Is there any other variation not included above?

Comment: 8 and 11 are  doubtful but not fatal (people will understand you). The rest is fine.

Comment: I would say 1,4,5,9,10,11 sounds OK. I would also add *Дорожка два метра в ширину.* as perfectly normal. "Имеет два метра ширины" sounds a bit odd to me. Probably OK in conversation, but not when written down. 
No 5 needs a dash: *У дорожки ширина **—** два метра.*

Comment: All these expressions and phrases are really correct. 
Also you can use verb "составляет". If you need. 
Ширина дорожки составляет два метра. :>

Comment: il--ya "Имеет два метра ширины" sounds a bit odd to me - нерусский, чтоль ? :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Дорожка шириной в два метра.

Sounds ok. Lots of examples in literature.
*К этому заветному месту вел переулок шириной в метр. [В. В. Овчинников. Калейдоскоп жизни (2003)]*

> 2. Дорожка в два метра ширины.

Doesn't sound good to me, I would change to *шириной* (making it effectively same as no 1). But this variant is possible and there are some examples in literature.
*Тотчас же по выходе из Ускова пришлось иметь дело с ручьем в сажень ширины, через который были перекинуты три тонких кривых бревна; все прошли благополучно, я же оступился и набрал в сапог. [А. П. Чехов. Остров Сахалин (1893-1895)]*
*Для прогулок русских моряков на берегу среди пустырей было отведено место в сорок шагов длины и двадцать шагов ширины. [Н. К. Чуковский. Капитан Крузенштерн (1930)]*

> 3. Двухметровая в ширину дорожка.

That sounds incorrect. *Двухметровая* is an adjective which is related to *дорожка*, and *в ширину* becomes incomplete. You can use either *два метра в ширину* or *двухметровая ширина* or *двухметровая дорожка*, but not *двухметровая в ширину*.

> 4. Ширина дорожки два метра.

This one is ok, except that it needs a dash to replace the missing verb *составляет*:
*Ширина дорожки — два метра.*

> 5. У дорожки ширина два метра.

Ok, but also needs a dash:
*У дорожки ширина — два метра.*

> 6. У дорожки два метра ширины.

Unnatural, sounds like *дорожка* is in possession of 2 meters of something called *ширина*.

> 7. У дорожки два метра в ширину.

Unnatural. Again sounds like *дорожка* is in possession of something, or there is something next to it.

> 8. Дорожка имеет два метра ширины.

Sounds unnatural to me, but there are some examples in literature. I suspect that this usage might be dated.
*Все три галереи были со сводами и имели около трех сажен ширины и четыре вышины. [Н. Э. Гейнце. Князь Тавриды (1898)]*

> 9. Дорожка имеет два метра в ширину.

I wouldn't use this phrasing, but it *is* possible.
*Сейнер наш имеет 16 метров в длину, 4 в ширину. [Василий Аксенов. Звездный билет // «Юность», 1961]*

> 10. Дорожка имеет в ширину два метра.

This is equivalent to no 9. Doesn't sound good to me, but it *is* possible.
*Корабль имел в длину 41 фут, в ширину ― 12 футов и осадку 5 футов. [Б. Г. Островский. Великая Северная экспедиция (1937)]*

> 11. Дорожка имеет ширину в два метра.

*ширина в два метра* doesn't sound right.

More variants:
*Дорожка имеет ширину два метра.*
*Ширина дорожки составляет два метра.*
*Дорожка двухметровой ширины.*

Comment: Number 8 is ok:                                                                                                                      Каждая рота имеет шесть сажен ширины [Салтыков-Щедрин. История одного города]

Comment: @MrDudulex I think you are right, I'll update the answer. Probably no. 8, as well as 2, 9 and 10 are dated.

Answer (score 1):

4. Ширина дорожки два метра.
5. У дорожки ширина два метра.
   Only these two are correct.

https://kover-russia.ru/catalog/kovrovye-dorozhki-shirinoj-2-metra/

Here's another correct example:

Дорожка шириной два метра.(don't use a preposition here)

People will understand any of the variants you gave, but that doesn't make them correct.

Comment: I wouldn't be so categorical. No 1: *К этому заветному месту вел переулок шириной в метр. [В. В. Овчинников. Калейдоскоп жизни (2003)]* No 9: *Сейнер наш имеет 16 метров в длину, 4 в ширину. [Василий Аксенов. Звездный билет // «Юность», 1961]* No 10: *Корабль имел в длину 41 фут, в ширину ― 12 футов и осадку 5 футов. [Б. Г. Островский. Великая Северная экспедиция (1937)]*

Comment: I think "переулок шириной в метр" is correct, but only in course of a longer sentence. It can't be a phrase on it's own. As I understood, we are talking about separate sentences (I presume they are either назывные or неполные).

Comment: All these expressions and phrases are really correct.

Comment: @Alexandr this phrase can be a complete sentence as a part of a dialog, or as a title or caption.